# Correctly printing a slice in go with Printf formatting

Tags: arrays, go, printf

I am trying to print a slice in go. The `fmt` documentation says to use `%p` with the address to the 0th element. This just gives the address of the slice. `%q` printed the slice in hex and I couldn't find a way to stop that.

What is the proper verb to use when printing a slice in go? (I currently just use %v which works)

```
func main() {
    slice := []int{0,1,2,3}
    fmt.Printf("slice: %p\n",slice)
}
//output is "slice: 0xc00007a000" or other memory address
//using &slice[0] is no different. Using slice[0] gives a type error
```

Comment: `%v` is the proper way.

Comment: The verb `%p` is for pointers (addresses). If you want the slice value, use `%v`.

Comment: What made you think %p could be the correct verb? Which part if the documentation of package fmt hinted %p could be useful?

Comment: @Volker I just realised I misread it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%v` is a good option in general, but you can also use the specifier for the
slice elements:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   {
      s := []int{10, 20, 30, 40}
      fmt.Printf("%d\n", s) // [10 20 30 40]
   }
   {
      s := []byte{'e', 'a', 's', 't'}
      fmt.Printf("%c\n", s) // [e a s t]
      fmt.Printf("%s\n", s) // east
      fmt.Printf("%q\n", s) // "east"
   }
   {
      s := []string{"east", "west"}
      fmt.Printf("%s\n", s) // [east west]
      fmt.Printf("%q\n", s) // ["east" "west"]
   }
}
```